# SSRS - number of values against a certain column

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum

I have a table showing two fields:

```
Location      Status

Location1     Current 
Location2     Current
Location3     Not Active
Location4     Not Active
Location5     Current
```

I would like to add a seperate table in my report to sumarise the data:

```
Status    Number of Partners

Current           3
Not Active        2
```

Is this possible within Visual Studio or should i think about doing it in SQL (it would be easier but just intruiged).

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can create a separate table... but its can be done within the same table by just adding a group by query as...

```
    select status, count(status) from table t group by status;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the separate table ? you can do :

```
select status, count(*)
fro table t
group by status;
```